# Fix right and left column, dynamic center column

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a three column layout where:

```
left-column fixed width: 200px
right-column fixed width: 300px
center-column dynamic width;
```

I can't seem to get this to work. Here is what I have so far:

```
#one {
    float:left;
    background-color: red;
    width: 300px;
    height: 20px;
}

#two {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 0 200px 0 300px;
}

#three {
    position: relative;            
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 200px;
    height: 20px;
    float: right;            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do:  Make your container whatever width you want it to be, make your left and right columns whatever size you want them to be fixed and then give the container `padding` on the left and right according to the widths of the two containers.  The middle container will be 100% of the width of the container which is now shrinking it because of the padding.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col">
        1
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        2
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        3
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    padding:0 300px 0 200px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
.col:nth-of-type(1) {
    width:200px;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    background-color:yellow;
}
.col:nth-of-type(3) {
    width:300px;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    background-color:blue;
}
.col:nth-of-type(2) {
    width:100%;
    background-color:green;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

when you use float, floatting element should be first in the flow, then static can come sit in between if enough room:
example

```css
#one {
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
  width: 300px;
}
#two {
  background-color: blue;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#three {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 200px;
  float: right;
}
/* demo purpose to show overflow purpose */
div {
  margin:0 5px;
  border:solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="one">
  1 i float .Run me full page too
</div>
<div id="three">
  3 i float
</div>
<div id="two">
  2 i'm there
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since bullshit IE versions pretty much died, you can use `calc` [safely](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc). Flexbox is a bit [tricky](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox), but you could consider it.

Anyway, with `calc`, just float them all and give the middle column a dynamic width. Easy does it.

```
.col-1 { float: left; width: 200px; }
.col-2 { float: left; width: calc(100% - 200px - 300px); }
.col-3 { float: left; width: 300px; }
```

Checkout [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/os5bs426/).

Answer (score 0):

**HTML** :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right></div>
    <div class="center">Content Goes Here</div>
</div>
```

**CSS** :

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
}
.left {
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
}
.right {
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
}
center {
    display:block;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```